# Aber: conjunction or adverb?

Tags: adverb, conjunction, word-classes

Can you help me with a problem? I don't understand if in the following sentence *aber* is a conjunction or adverb! Thank you!

> Er war groß und bullig und hatte fast keinen Hals, dafür *aber* einen sehr großen Schnurrbart.
>
> (Harry Potter und der Stein der Weisen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither.

In this very specific case, "aber" is in fact a *[particle](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partikel_(Grammatik))*. Particles are, in German, somewhat like a sprinkle of salt over a meal - They are not really necessary (try to leave it off, the sentence will still mean the same), but intensify the notion (here, *aber* intensifies the contrast).

(Note that the definition of a *particle* in German grammar differs quite a bit from the same (more classically used) term in English)

Comment: But "nicht" is considered to be a particle as well, and it definitely can't be left out without a significant change of meaning. So your answer is a bit misleading.

Comment: "nicht" can act as a special case, the *Negationspartikel* and you can't leave those out.  "Nicht" can also be used as a "Modalpartikel", and can be left off, like in "Möchten sie nicht heute Abend mit mir Essen gehen". That would however, better be an extra question.

Comment: I don't think there's any universal agreement on what a "particle" is across languages; it ends up being a odds and ends category for things that are difficult to classify. One requirement though is that they aren't inflected. A typical example, Japanese adds *ka* to mark a question instead of changing word order. So what do you call *ka*? It doesn't seem to fit any traditional category so call it a particle.

Comment: @RDBury No, there is no such universal agreement. Not between languages, and sometimes not even within a language. In German, the "traditional" approach was to call everything non-flexed a particle - this included  (Adverb, Präposition, Konjunktion) - and I think this is still the approach in English grammar, for example. A newer understanding excludes these three from the definition, but it's still something like a "miscellaneous" word classification. The closest definition today I was trying to give above (grain of salt)

Comment: My understanding is that the functional difference in German between a particle and an adverb, at least for some sources, is that an adverb can be placed that the start of a sentence. I'm not sure that's a helpful distinction though. A verb is a word that describes what someone/something is doing; when understand the function then it's meaningful to say that the verb comes second in a sentence. You don't define a verb as a word that comes second in a sentence. Then the verb placement rule is a tautology.

Comment: @RDBury Not quite - an adverb is exactly what its name says - It goes with the verb and modifies it. A particle is not associated with the verb, actually it's associated with nothing in the sentence. Look at "Das ist ja eine schöne Bescherung" - Here the particle "ja" is associated with nothing but the whole sentence and  just adds a bit of "spice" to it.

Comment: It depends how you define adverbs, both German and English have "sentence adverbs". For example "Eigentlich gibt es gar keinen Weihnachtsmann." (Source, Wiktionary.) To me, "Eigentlich" is an adverb, "gar" is a particle, neither one describes "geben".

Comment: @RDBury Apparently, our "Sprachgefühl" seems to differ: I would very clearly see the "eigentlich" modifying the verb in your example, the "gar" definitely not.

Answer (score -5):

> "Er war groß und bullig und hatte fast keinen Hals, dafür aber einen sehr großen Schnurrbart".

Diese Formulierung, die, wie @tofro oben schon beschreibt, relativ gut in der Umgangssprache integriert ist, dürfte in anbetracht der Logik mit englischem *even* vergleichbar sein: *he had barely a neck, but an **even** bigger mustache*; oder anders mit *ever*, *an ever so big mustache*.

This can't be argued without *dafür*. In view of French *en lieu, plutôt*, obsolete *ains* "instead of" and conj. *ainsi* respectively, the etymon *ante ius "before ..." implies that German *für* (anstelle von, für jemanden einspringen) respectively *vor*, likewise *eher als* and English *rather, sooner than* is _ formally identical_ with this use of *aber*, inasmuch as either *dafür* or *aber* can be removed without change of semantics. Which is to imply that *da-* is a preglottalized *je-, e-*, viz. *jeh, eh, ever*, cp. *ius*, above. Now that I've taken it appart, I'm afraid I can't piece it back together.